# expression inside ng-class

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a very simple Angular App and I'm trying to use ng-repeat in conjunction with ng-class to repeat a template and apply a different class to the outer div depending on one of the properties of the data being bound.

this worked when I used a simple...

```
ng-class="message.type"
```

...but unfortunately I need to concatenate a string to the start of the message type.

I tried to create a JSfiddle here...

http://jsfiddle.net/XuYGN/5/

... but it's my first attempt at making a JSfiddle too and I must be doing something wrong because the Angular stuff doesn't seem to be running. It does show what I'm trying to do with the expression though.

Any help would really be appreciated.

Comment: It works ok [here](http://jsfiddle.net/XuYGN/7/), but are you sure you need to use `ng-class`, and not the simple `class`?

Comment: If you change `onLoad` to `no wrap(body)` the JSFiddle will run the AngularJS code like you are expecting.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

html :

```
    <div ng-controller="mainCtrl">

        <div ng-repeat="message in data.messages" ng-class="'className-' + message.type">

            Repeat Me           

        </div>        

    </div>                

</div>
```

javascript :

```
var mainCtrl=function($scope) {

    $scope.data = {}

    $scope.data.messages = [
        {
            "type": "phone"},
        {
            "type": "email"},
        {
            "type": "meeting"},
        {
            "type": "note"}
    ]
```

}​

in the fiddle you put some {{}} around the expression dont do it because it is an expression.

Answer (score 11):

FYI, an alternative to what @camus answered:

```
class="{{'className-' + message.type}}"
```

When using `class`, the expression (inside {{}}s) must evaluate to a string of space-delimited class names.

When using [`ng-class`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngClass), the  expression must evaluate to one of the following:

1. a string of space-delimited class names, or
2. and array of class names, or
3. a map/object of class names to boolean values.

Comment: another alternative to this would be `class="className-{{message.type}}"`

Comment: @MichaelStramel any idea what the reason might be for this to work in everything except IE? "It's IE!" type answers are not accepted...

Comment: @MichaelStramel in angular, when you use angular variables inside the class declaration (as in your example), you should avoid that, and use ng-class instead, for performance reasons when the page loads.
If you use class="className-{{...}}" the page will interpret "className-{{...}}" as a string while the {{..}} is not resolved and display it onscreen. If you use ng-class, it won't display anything while the {{..}} is not resolved. This way, with ng-class you won't get the ugly code shown onscreen. In faster internet connections this is not noticeable, but it is in slower internets.